# Interact with solidity contract using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts

I started working on a simple project and I don't have much experience in blockchain. I want to connect to a Solidity contract using JavaScript. Connecting with the contract and getting the address works, but when i'm calling getInfo I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are
retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist,
or querying a node which is not fully synced.
```

Below is the code.
The contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract NFT {
    uint256 id;
    string name;
    string description;
    address owner;

    constructor(uint256 _id, string memory _name, string memory _description) public {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
        description = _description;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transfer(address newOwner) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can transfer the NFT");
        owner = newOwner;
    }

    function getInfo() public view returns (uint256, string memory, string memory, address) {
        return (id, name, description, owner);
    }

    function getAddress() external view returns(address) {
        return address(this);
    }
}
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
    const connectContract = async () => {
        const contractAbi = [
            {
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "newOwner",
                        "type": "address"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "transfer",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "_id",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "string",
                        "name": "_name",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "string",
                        "name": "_description",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "constructor"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "getAddress",
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "address"
                    }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "getInfo",
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "string",
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "string",
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "address"
                    }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            }
        ]; // the ABI of the NFT contract

        const contractAddress =[contract address]; // the address of the deployed NFT contract
        window.web3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
        window.contract = await new window.web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
        document.getElementById("contractArea").innerHTML = "Connected to Contract";
        web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
    }

    const getInfo = async () => {
        const info = await contract.methods.getInfo().call().then(console.log);
    }

    async function main() {

        const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);

        // Transfer the NFT to a new owner
        const newOwner = [owner];
        const receipt = await contract.methods.transfer(newOwner).send({ from: web3.eth.defaultAccount });
        console.log(receipt);
    }
```

Is this the correct way to connect with a smart contract? What am I missing?

Comment: Since you're using `window.ethereum` provider (likely MetaMask or other browser wallet), is the wallet connected to the same network/environment where the contract is deployed at?

Comment: @PetrHejda Yes, that was the problem, the network was different, I get it now. Thank you very much!